# Proof that inverse of a matrix is unique

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

*If B and C are both inverses of the matrix A,then B=C*.

Can't i prove it in following way ?

Proof:

`AB=BA=I` and `AC=CA=I`,then `BA=CA=I`

By postmultiplication $\Rightarrow (BA)(A^{-1})=(CA)(A^{-1})=(I)(A^{-1})\Rightarrow B=C=A^{-1}$,

or by premultiplication $AB=AC=I\Rightarrow (A^{-1})(AB)=(A^{-1})(AC)=(A^{-1})(I)\Rightarrow B=C=A^{-1}$.

Comment: What does $A^{-1}$ mean before uniqueness of the inverse has been established?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Actually the proof is available in any linear algebra book. My main intention was to prove it by myself. As it was not the same as in the book, i wanted to check whether it makes sense.

Comment: Yes but it's unnecessarily complicated since your proof assumes the existence of three inverses while two are enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is much much simpler.

$B=BI=B(AC)=(BA)C=IC=C$